# How to get height of a mapped object

Tags: jquery, html

I have three jQuery objects in an array, like so:

```
<div class="object"></div>
<div class="object"></div>
<div class="object"></div>

<script>
var arr = $('.object');
</script>
```

And I want to use `$.map()` to find the heights of each and store them in an array, like this:

```
var arrElHeights = $.map(arr, function(a){
    return a.height();
});
```

How would I accomplish this? Should I be iterating through via another method instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea. The problem is that height is not a function. What you want to do is to get the clientHeight of the element. Try something like this:

```
 var arrElHeights = $.map(arr, function(a){
    return a.clientHeight;
});
```

Here is some info on clientHeight : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight

and also the docs on offsetHeight : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

Jquery .height() does not include padding

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the full difference between `clientHeight` and `height`. I'm currently looking around for resources, but if you have any you would like to suggest, please add it to the answer.

Comment: @Shane, Check my answer please

Answer (score 1):

**More details**

`a` isn't `jQuery` object, you may try `$(a).height()` or `a.clientHeight` or `a.offsetHeight`, or even `a.scrollHeight`.

`clientHeight` includes the height and vertical padding.

`offsetHeight` includes the height, vertical padding, and vertical borders.

`scrollHeight` includes the height of the contained document (would be greater than just height in case of scrolling), vertical padding, and vertical borders.

I think when you include `jQuery`, you should use it in all your codes.